# How can I run a python script using Anaconda from the command line?

Tags: command-line, python

*Note: I'm new to Python and I've never really used external modules like the ones listed below so feel free to let me know if there's anything I could be doing better in order to get my program up and running.*

I'm currently working with a python (2.7.x) program that requires the use of the [SciPy](http://scipy.org/) stack. The previous developer of the program was using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) in order to access all external modules. In my case, I need to be able to run the entire program with a single command. For example:

```
python myFile.py
```

Will execute myFile.py (which has the following imports):

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

From what I understand, Anaconda is an IDE that requires you to execute code in a similar way to Visual Studios (i.e. a "Run" button). So my question is:

**Is there a way for me to do this directly from the command line?**

*Note: The reason I'm specifying the use of Anaconda instead of just using the external modules themselves is because on the SciPy website there's constant mention that it's easiest to just use a scientific python distribution like Anaconda or Python(x,y). **Ultimately, I'm okay with any solution that allows me to run my program with the above imports.***

Comment: Not really, anaconda tries to make a Python that is independent of the Python installed on the OS.  It uses the `conda` command to manage environments, e.g. `conda env list`.  The environments are not that different from `virtualenv` and use a script called `activate` that need to be sourced, e.g. `source activate <env>`.  But my experience with anaconda is pretty limited so I may be wrong about some parts.

Comment: just type the name of the program you want to run. e.g if you are inside the required environment and want to run program called spades. type spades and give the file directory and output name etc

Answer (score 20):

1. Create required Anaconda environment
   `conda create --name environmentName python=3 pandas numpy`.
   Include all your dependencies at once while creating the environment.
2. Switch to the environment with `conda activate environmentName`.
3. Executing the python script `python fileName.py`.
   You don't have to specify the python version because the script is running inside the Anaconda environment. The version used will be whatever is specified in the environment (the script required python3 which has already been specified in Anaconda environment).

Comment: More about managing environments with Conda: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question and the answer
regarding step 3 it didn't work when I ran `python setup.py` or `python3 setup.py`
step 3 didn't work with me
it worked when I ran

```
pip install .
```

in the desired directory which have setup.py which you can download as zip from github for your package you want to instal
I am using conda environment in Ubuntu (bioconda3)